# overriding iterator in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, linked-list

I have made a general abstract linked list (AbstractList) which is holding Data*, and has inner class Iterator. Then, I made a linked list which is deriving from AbstractList, for Job class objects, which is called JobList.

The problem is, I cannot implement operator* in the Iterator class in AbstractList because it has to return Data which is abstract.

So, I thought I had to implement it in the deriving class JobList, but I just can't.
Here's the code, where did I go wrong?

```
class AbstractList
{
protected:
....//Node code
....

Node *m_head;
int m_len;

public:
    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        Node *curr;
    public:
        Iterator(Node* nd): curr(nd){}
        Iterator(const Iterator& it) {curr=it.curr;}
        Iterator operator++() {curr=curr->getNext(); return *this;}
        bool operator==(const Iterator& other) {return curr==other.curr;}
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) {return curr!=other.curr;}
       //here I should implement operator *, but I can't, so I do it in JobList
    };
    Iterator begin() {return Iterator(m_head);}

    AbstractList();
    ~AbstractList();

    virtual void setNewNode(Data*)=0;
    Data *getFirst() const {return m_head->getData();}
};
```

and the deriving class JobList:

```
class JobList: public AbstractList
{
public:
    void setNewNode(Job*);
    Job *getFirst() const {return (Job*)AbstractList::GetFirst();}

    //here I want to implement operator*, but everything I've tried failed.
    //How should it be done?
};
```

EDIT: 
I tried to put the following code in the Iterator in AbstractList:

```
Data *operator*() {return curr->getData();}
```

And this code in the deriving class JobList:

```
Job *Iterator::operator*() {return (Job*)Iterator::operator*}
```

But I get the following erorr:
 'JobList' : class contains explicit override '*' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't"?  Why can't you?

Comment: `"Where did I go wrong?"` At the *very* beginning, where you decided to do this with derivation instead of templates (or, arguably, even earlier, where you decided to do this, instead of using existing code like `std::list` or (probably better) `std::priority_queue`).